# C++ Need to enable class member variables to access an std::vector of instances of another class

Tags: c++, class

I am working on an API that is supposed to allow you to draw simple geometric shapes and calculate their elements. The project is based on the SFML library.

I have this class:

```cpp
#ifndef POINT_H_INCLUDED
#define POINT_H_INCLUDED

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Helper.h"

class Point : public AbstractShape
{
public:
    Point(float x, float y);

    Vector getCoords();
    sf::VertexArray getShape();
    void setLabel(std::string label, int param);
private:
    float m_x, m_y, m_R;
    std::string m_label;
    sf::VertexArray m_shape;
    sf::Text m_labelObject;
};

#endif
```

It inherits from the abstract class `AbstractShape`, just like other similar classes `Segment` and `Triangle`. I need this to be able to add the different shapes to a single container to process them conveniently in one place later on.

In the `main` function, I declare the container, then create an instance of `Point` and then `push_back` it to the container:

```cpp
std::vector<AbstractShape*> shapes;
Point* p1 = new Point(100, 50);
p1->setLabel("A", 4);
shapes.push_back(p1);
```

I think it would be better if the instance could add itself to the container when the instance is created. To do that, the `Point` class should be able to see container from within itself. What is the best way to achieve this while not introducing too much coupling to the `Point` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add itself to the container, the `Point` needs to be coupled with the container. Coupling the two seems like a bad idea: *why should the `Point` know anything about `std::vector`*?

If you use this pattern often in your code, it's better to define a function to instantiate and add the point to a container:

```
template<typename T=std::vector<Point*>>
Point *makePoint(int x, int y, T container) {
  Point *p = new Point(x, y);
  container.push_back(p);
  return p; // so we can set other properties easily
}
```

Or to create another `Context` class which encapsulates the set of points:

```
template <typename T=std::vector<Point*>>
class Context {
   T container;
public:
   Point* addPoint(int x, int y) {
     Point *p = new Point(x, y);
     container.push_back(p);
     return p;
   }
};
```

Also you may wish to use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` to avoid memory leaks, though this may get a bit messy with inheritence.

[Here's a fully WME on Ideone](http://ideone.com/KGMG3q) with the 2nd option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    public:
    Point (int x, int y) {}
};

template <typename T=std::vector<Point*>>
class Context {
   T container;
public:
   Point* addPoint(int x, int y) {
     Point *p = new Point(x, y);
     container.push_back(p);
     return p;
   }
};

int main() {
    Context<> c;
    c.addPoint(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union" for line `container.push_back(p)`. (I'm using the second implementation, that involves the `Context` class).

Comment: @Rokas oups, pls see my update and the MWE on Ideone; TLDR use `std::vector<Point*>` instead of `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

> I think it would be better if the instance could add itself to the
>   container when the instance is created.

This is your decision, but think twice on it - in most situations it is better to keep objects as simple as possible. If you need just to simplify your code, this can be made:

You can make **external construction function**, similar to [std::make_share](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and [std::make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

This will make you able to call:

```
construct<Point>(container, 1, 2);
construct<Line>(container, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

And it will construct Point/Line and put into container in one line

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct AbstractShape
{
    virtual std::ostream& dump(std::ostream&) = 0;
};
struct Point : AbstractShape
{
    Point(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}


    virtual std::ostream& dump(std::ostream& o) override
    {
        return o << "P[" << x << ":" << y << "]";
    }
    float x, y;
};
struct Line : AbstractShape
{
    Line(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) : x1(x1), y1(y1), x2(x2), y2(y2) {}

    virtual std::ostream& dump(std::ostream& o) override
    {
        return o << "L[" << x1 << ":" << y1 << "," << x2 << ":" << y2<< "]";
    }

    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

template<typename Object, typename Container, typename ...Args>
Object* construct(Container& c, Args... args)
{
    Object* res = new Object(args...);
    c.push_back(res);
    return res;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<AbstractShape*> container;

    construct<Point>(container, 1, 2);
    construct<Line>(container, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    for (auto s : container)
        s->dump(std::cout) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
P[1:2]
L[1:2,3:4]
```

[**Live test**](http://ideone.com/n7WR88)

And I definitely recommend using [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers